# Formal limit definition in $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x^2+2}{9x}=+\infty$

Tags: limits, definition, epsilon-delta

Using the limit definition, show that:

$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x^2+2}{9x}=+\infty$

I get blocked when I use the equation:

**Definition**

$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+\infty$

$f(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ tends to $ \infty$ if and only if $$ \forall A>0, \exists B>0 \ \mbox{ such that} \ \forall x \ \mbox{where} \ x>B, \\ f(x)>A$$

but I do not know how to continue

Comment: What have you tried, or what are you blocked on? You've just written out the definition of the limit. Why haven't you tried, say, finding such a $V$ as a function of $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x>0$ we have that

$$\dfrac{x^2+2}{9x}>\dfrac{x^2}{9x}=\dfrac{x}{9}.$$

Thus

$$x>B\implies \dfrac{x^2+2}{9x}>\dfrac{x}{9}=\dfrac{B}{9}.$$

So, consider $B=9A$ and you are done.

Answer (score -1):

For a given $A>0$, let $B = 9A$. Then we have that:

$$x > 9A \implies f(x) = \frac{x^2+2}{9x} = \frac x9 + \frac{2}{9x} > \frac x9 > A$$

Hence the proof.

Comment: I would be interested in discussing my mistake (if any) with the downvoter

Comment: Some people downvote just because THEY are jerks, nothing to do with the answer they are downvoting. I am sure the downvoter has no interest in discussing anything with you. That's SO for you.

Comment: @mathguy I would prefer for voting on posts to be transparent.

Comment: I would prefer not to have a reputation system at all. No one cares what I would prefer. I assume it's the same for you.